# Try Catch don't work properly

Tags: google-apps-script, try-catch

I,m triyng to create a folder if it doesn't exist and i'm using try/catch but a few days ago has stopped working. This is the code. Thanks a lot.

```
try {
var folders = alumnospath.getFolders();
while (folders.hasNext()) {
 var folderp = folders.next();
 var folderalumno = folderp.getName();
 if (folderalumno == alumno2) {
 var folderid = folderp.getId();
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);}}}
catch (e){
var foldere = DriveApp.getFolderById(alumnospathid).createFolder(alumno2).getId();
var folder = alumnospath.getFolderById(foldere);} 

catch (e){
var foldere = DriveApp.getFolderById(alumnospathid).createFolder(alumno2).getId();
var folder = alumnospath.getFolderById(foldere);}
folder.createFile(pdf);
```

The error is (translate from spanish): TypeError: can't call method "createFile" from undefined.

The trouble is that the script stops in catch(e) and no executes this.

Comment: That error tells you that no folder was found by `getFolderById(alumnospathid)`. You don't show how you get `alumnospathid`, but that is what you need to investigate.

Comment: also : why do you have 2 "catch(e)" in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless `alumno2` is a variable of string type, then this line:

```
if (folderalumno == alumno2) {
```

will probably never evaluate as true, and therefore not get the file and folder ID.

if `alumno2` is the name of the folder you want, the code should be:

```
if (folderalumno == "alumno2") {
```

put into quotes.